# How to validate Maven Repos came from public or corporate repo

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

New to java and Intellij, Little confused how to validate maven repos pulled from public or corporate remote repo.

I have specified remote repos in settings.xml and removed below from pom.xml

<maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>

TIA

Comment: The header has nothing to do with the compiler? Can explain more detail what you exactly mean and what you problem is?

Comment: I want to pull repos using settings.xml only for intellij java project. I want to avoid situation where any repo is pulled from public repos. How i can make sure that?

Comment: Are you in a coporate environment?

Comment: yes i am in a corporate environment

Comment: In a corporate environment you should have only one repository defined in your settings.xml which redirects everything to your repository manager ... so having multiple repositories sounds already wrong... And there is no settings.xml only for IDEA Intellij or for your env. You should use the same...

Comment: Can you provide sample settings.xml for reference?